# Why json.keys() get keys in different order

Tags: python, json

Hi i have the following code in python:

```
import json
jsonpost = json.loads('{"Player": {"_id": "3","firstName":"kim","surname":"jones"},"newTable": {"_id": "4","SurName": "abcd"}}')

for key in jsonpost.keys():
    for innerkey in jsonpost[key]:
        print innerkey
```

my question is why when i print out inner key the order of the keys for jsonpost['Player'] is the following:

```
_id , surname, firstName
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered in Python.

Comment: Maps have no specified order, but are merely an association of key to value. Do you need them to be in a particular order?

Comment: Dictionaries usually don't have a guaranteed order. It's an implementation detail, as they're not built to be iterated over. I think Python has a package called "odict" for this purpose.

Comment: The same is true of JSON (unordered set of key/value pairs) per the spec: http://json.org/

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries are implemented internally with a hash table. This means that key order is not preserved. Is this an issue?

Comment: yes i need to get the keys in order

Answer (score 1):

keys in a dictionary are never in the same order, if you want them consistently in the same order for your code, you could do

```
sorted(jsonpost.keys())
```

Comment: Never? Or consistently for the lifetime of a script execution?

Answer (score 1):

Either JavaScript's `JSON` nor Python's `dict` have the concept of ordering. You can use `collections.OrderedDict` in Python to get away with it, but JavaScript does not have such an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are inherently unordered, so when you print them out, the keys can be out of order.

If order is important, you can use an `OrderedDict`:

```
import collections
jsonpost = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(jsonpost.items()))
```

Or you can change to for loop to:

```
for key in sorted(jsonpost.keys()):
    for innerkey in jsonpost[key]:
        print innerkey
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary ordering is specified as being unspecified, you could `sort(whatever.keys())` or you could use and ordered dictionary, i.e. `collections.OrderedDict` if you are running python  2.7 or later.